# create routing for multi module angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I am new to angular. I have a multi-module structure in angular app e.g login, user, report etc. each module has one or two component. I want to implement routing but login page should display first. when the user is on the login window navigation should not display. when user login it redirects to the dashboard. on the dashboard, navbar should display & when user click on any menu that component should display below the navbar.

currently, when I click on a menu it redirects to that component & hide the navbar.

```js
//app.routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }, 
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }, 
  { path: 'user', component: AddUserComponent }, 
  { path: 'trello', component: TrelloDataComponent }, 
  { path: 'calender', component: CalenderComponent }, 
  { path: 'clockify', component: ClockifyDataComponent }, 
  { path: 'rescueAll', component: AllDataComponent }, 
  { path: 'rescueDate', component: AllDataComponent }, 
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

// app.module.ts

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    CalModule,
    ClokifyModule,
    LoginModule,
    RescueModule,
    TrelloModule,
    UserModule,
    PagenotfoundModule
  ]
```

```html
 //app.component.html
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: go through with the link https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules and also look lazy loading

Comment: Where is your navbar template defined? If you are rendering the menu components in a router-outlet of a html file which doesn't have the navbar template, it won't be rendered on navigation to those component.

Comment: <a class="link mar-l-r-1" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/rescueAll']">All Data</a>
<a class="link mar-l-r-1" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/user']">Add User</a>
  <a class="link mar-l-r-1" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/clockify']">Clokify Data</a>
<a class="link mar-l-r-1" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/trello']">Trello Data</a>
  <a class="link mar-l-r-1" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/calender']">Calender</a> 
this is navbar template

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in the comments, extract your **navbar** outside in the app.component.html so it will be   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

The router outlet tag will get replaced according to your current URL, so if you want to have your navbar visibe at all times, you either

1. include it in every single component - bad idea, as it is duplication of code and a lot of unnecessary rendering
2. extract it outside --> good practice of doing it.

if you still want to hide it, for instance on the login screen, you can do so with the navbar component, with watching the currently active url, something like this:

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute
      .params
      .subscribe(
        params => {
          console.log("current url parameters:", params);
        }
      );
  }
```

And depending in the current url, you can hide or show (for instance with `*ngIf` the navbar.